# FilterRegistrationBean не видит бин указанный в registrationBean.addInitParameter

Tags: java, spring, boot, bean

Есть класс -

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebDavConfig
```

В нем инициализируется набор параметров -

```
private final WebDavAuthHelper webDavAuthHelper;
private final WebDavLockManager webDavLockManager;
private final WebDavService webDavService;
```

Также в нем инициализируется

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SpringMiltonFilter> miltonFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SpringMiltonFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new SpringMiltonFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/webdav/*");
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("contextConfigClass", WebDavConfig.class.getName());

        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Соответвенно в процессе запуска отваливается

```
2020-06-22 21:02:46,806 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] Exception starting filter [springMiltonFilter]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webDavConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 's.s.sce.service.storage.webdav.WebDavAuthHelper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

(бины туда в принципе не автовайрятся, но они сущетсвуют и их видит AppContext)

Однако если поменять аннотацию @Configuration -> @Component или убрать

```
registrationBean.addInitParameter("contextConfigClass", WebDavConfig.class.getName());
```

Все заводится. Какая может быть природа такого поведения?

Comment: что значит не автовайрятся? вы повесили на класс WebDavConfig аннтоацию  RequiredArgsConstructor. Все поля этого класса final , а это значит, что в этом классе вам силами ломбок добавился единственный конструктор с 3 параметрами. Если конструктор единственный, то никаких доп.аннотаций в духе Autowired больше ставит не нужно. Ваш класс помечен как Configuration, а значит это бин, а значит спринг при его создании будет использовать ваш единственнй конструктор и проинициализирует все поля. Именно при этом вы получаете ошибку (при инциализации поля  WebDavAuthHelper). Смотрите на WebDavAuthHelper

Comment: Под "автовайрятся" имелось ввиду инжектятся/находятся. Аннотаций Autowired там и не стоит.
+Он ни один бин из тех, что должны попасть в конструктор не видит, если их просто поменять местами и написать ручками конструктор то будет падать другой бин